# Why javac adds clone-method and how java separates and links methods with same signature?

Tags: java, javac, bytecode, signature

Let's look at the following example.

```
public class T1 implements Cloneable {
    private T1(T1 g) {}

    public T1 clone() { return new T1(this); }
}
```

There are two clone methods in a bytecode.

```
$ javac T1.java
$ javap -s T1
Compiled from "T1.java"
public class T1 implements java.lang.Cloneable {
  public T1 clone();
    descriptor: ()LT1;

  public java.lang.Object clone() throws java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException;
    descriptor: ()Ljava/lang/Object;
}
```

These two methods have different result type and the same input signature. If I try to add a second method to code I will get a compile time error.

```
    public T1     clone() { return new T1(this); }
    public Object clone() { return null; }
...
$ java T1.java
T1.java:7: error: method clone() is already defined in class T1
    public Object clone() { return (null); }
```

So why javac adds the second method? And how java links methods with the same input signature?

Comment: but in other user defined classes no clone method in bytecode

Comment: I believe this always happens when you narrow a return type in an override.

Comment: This happens because for the Java Compiler two methods with the same argument types but different return types are the same method (i.e. the Java Compiler doesn't differentiate methods solely by return type), but for the JVM (which executes the compiled code) these are different methods (i.e. for the JVM they **are** different methods).

Comment: @Jorn No it isn’t. That’s not an inherited method. It is put there by the compiler, into this bytecode.

Comment: @Jorn since Java 5, you can override a method with a more specific return type.